# How can i solve these ASP redirect error?

Tags: asp-classic

I put these sentence on the top of index.asp file

> <% RESPONSE.REDIRECT "URL" %>

I've faced error
[image: error]

I also tried to put these sentence on the top of index.asp file

> #include virtual=".\ssl.asp"

as remark

and made ssl.asp file with these datas

[image: re]

Comment: Can you translate the error to english? Is there an error number?

Comment: Looks like you have an issue with character encoding as well, are the pages correctly using UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Presumably the page loads fine if you don't redirect and it's on the same URL or a domain you host? Do you have a HTTP_REFERER check of some kind? Because it looks like it's throwing an error you've set but with some encoding issues. Any ASP errors or the default "An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator." error should display just fine, never mind what encoding settings you're using.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear. It may cover two realities :

1. Using `<% RESPONSE.REDIRECT "URL" %>` won't work because **"URL"** is a string not containing a valid url.
2. If you want to redirect to a valid url that is defined in a **String variable named URL**, then you would have to use something like :

   `Dim URL`

   `URL = "https://somwhere.yourwebsite.com/yourpage.asp"`

   `RESPONSE.REDIRECT URL`